# How to convert from IPv6 to IPv4, and from there to an integer format

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipv6, ipv4

How do I convert an IPv6 address to an IPv4 address, and likewise how do I then parse the IPv4 address into a set of integers?

I have :

> a = ' ff06::c3'

I would like:

> 4278583296.0.0.195

And from there I would like to get:

> a1 = 4278583296
>   a2 = 0
>   a3 = 0
>   a4 = 195

Comment: ipv6 -> ipv4 -> int

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please write your solution first.

Comment: I've tidied up your question, as it was not clear at all what you were trying to achieve. Please pay some attention to formatting. The more effort you put into your question, the more likely someone is going to be to help you. We are all volunteers here, so we kind off expect some effort on your part. And in that spirit, please show us what you have tried already so that we can actually help you solve your problem instead of us solving it for you.

Comment: And besides the question formatting: that's not how IP addresses work. An IPv6 address is 128 bits and an IPv4 address is 32 bits, so what you're asking is impossible.

Comment: ff06::c3 translates to ff06:0:0:0:0:0:0:c3, not ff06:0:0:c3.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd ever want such a thing, since it doesn't correspond in any way to how IP addresses actually work, but you can use Python3.3's `ipaddress` module to easily parse your string. If you aren't on Python3.3, you'll have to write your own parser for IPv6 addresses that will expand them to their exploded form (`"0123:4567:89ab:cdef:fedc:ba98:7654:3210"`)

```
import ipaddress

myIP = ipaddress.ip_address('ff06::c3')
```

then convert to string with `IPv6Address.exploded` and grab each hextet using `str.split(":")`

```
hextets = myIP.exploded.split(":")
```

then map each pair of hextets into one 32-bit group and parse to int with `int(grp, base=16)`

```
import itertools

# from itertools recipes
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

new_groups = [int(a+b, base=16) for (a, b) in grouper(hextets, 2)]
# N.B. that a+b here is string concatenation, not addition
```

Then you can use `str.join` and `map` to put it all together into one dotted "IPv4" address

```
ipv4ish = '.'.join(map(str, new_groups))
```

and tuple unpacking to get each separate argument

```
a1, a2, a3, a4 = new_groups
```

Answer (score -2):

Method-1 :
Frist Step you will have to do is expand the IPV6. Once, you expand convert it to decimal. Once you have decimal vale convert to binary and then at last use formula to calculating IPV4 using binary.

Method-2 :
You can use python lib "netaddr" ( NOTE: You will need to install the lib follow this instruction http://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html )

Then you can import the "netaddr: in you code and use define similar method as below code

```
>>> IPNetwork('::ffff:192.0.2.1/119').ipv6()
IPNetwork('::ffff:192.0.2.1/119')
>>> IPNetwork('::ffff:192.0.2.1/119').ipv6(ipv4_compatible=True)
IPNetwork('::192.0.2.1/119')
>>> IPNetwork('::ffff:192.0.2.1/119').ipv4()
IPNetwork('192.0.2.1/23')
>>> IPNetwork('::192.0.2.1/119').ipv4()
IPNetwork('192.0.2.1/23')
```

Comment: I consider this answer incorrect because A) it doesn't accomplish what OP wants (which is, in this answer's defense, incomprehensible) and B) it recommends downloading a third-party module when `ipaddress` has been in the stdlib since Py3.3 (September 29, 2012)